# My shopping cart won't reset (javascript function)

Tags: javascript, html, css, function

I have a issue with the shopping cart. Everytime i am clicking on the add cart "button" it shows the the numbers to the shopping cart, after i reload the page the numbers are still there. Any suggestion on how i can reset after reloading the page?

```
// CART FUNCTION
function cart(name, price, url, con, btncart) {
  var item = {
    name: name,
    price: price,
    url: url
  };
  cartItems.push(item);
  let storage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart"));
  if (storage == null) {
    products.push(item);
    localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(products));
  } else {
    products = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart"));
    products.push(item);
    localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(products));
  }
  products = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart"));
  cart_n.innerHTML = `[${products.length}]`;
  // Take off display = none so the button won't dissapear!
  document.getElementById(btncart).style.display = "none";
  animation();
}
function cart2(name, price, url, con, btncart) {
  var item = {
    name: name,
    price: price,
    url: url
  };
  cartItems.push(item);
  let storage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart"));
  if (storage == null) {
    products.push(item);
    localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(products));
  } else {
    products = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart"));
    products.push(item);
    localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(products));
  }
  products = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart"));
  cart_n.innerHTML = `[${products.length}]`;
  document.getElementById(btncart).style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: You're storing the cart products in local storage. Even if you reload, data in local storage persists and shown in the cart. That's the whole point of using local storage. If you don't want this behavior, don't use local storage.

Comment: You are using localStorage to store the result which persists. So, just clear the data related to card from the localStorage when the page loads. You can use [onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload) for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code,

```
window.onload = function() {
    localStorage.removeItem("cart")
};
```